# PHP web proxy or web site forwarding

Tags: php, web-applications

Hello Guys! I have some problems with accessing some sites like facebook, so I need web proxy with PHP. I have looked for many open source web proxies, but I prefer to write my own. I want to do this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/facebook (which is located in remote server)
should open http://www.facebook.com ,
but it should not just open it,
the requests must be done using IP address of remote server.
```

How can I manage this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Somewhat ominous question given all the news about bots terrorizing Facebook.

Comment: @MikeB Nice one :) From what I read today though, it sounds more like fake accounts terrorizing Facebook advertisers.

Comment: @MikeB What do you mean? I could not understand you?

Comment: http://www.cnn.com/2012/08/02/tech/social-media/facebook-fake-accounts/index.html?hpt=te_t1

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help 
zend2.com

facebook using SSL connections because of that some of php proxies can't access facebook

Answer (score 0):

try using the function fsock.
You can learn from this simple proxy
http://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/